# Get mouse coordinates relative to Qt OpenGL widget

Tags: qt, opengl, widget

I get my mouse coordinates like this:

```
 winX = QCursor::pos().x();
```

These are coordinates for the whole screen. I need to get coordinates that are relative to my OpenGL widget window's viewport, so I can use the gluUnProject function.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to have a look at QWidget's [`mapFromGlobal(const QPoint & pos)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapFromGlobal) method.

As per the documentation this:

> translates the global screen coordinate pos to widget coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! 

I used:
     winX = this->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x();
 winY = this->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).y();

Comment: Glad that helped. It would be nicer though if you made that call just once and retrieved your x and y values from that result. Just a hint. :)

Comment: It's fast enough atm for my use :)

Comment: just a bit more ugly than the solution @Bart proposed.